# Understanding the operator "less" or "greater" in assigning value with C++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, assignment-operator, comparison-operators, relational-operators

I used greater than and less than signs and it gives ouput! How it is working ?

```
int x = 2;
x >= 3;
cout << x;  // output is 2
```

And also the output is different like this

```
int x = 2;
x = x > 3;
cout << x;   // output is zero !! HOW ??
```

Comment: `x >= 3;` is `(x > 3) || (x == 3);` and the result is discarded.  It is **not** a shorthand assignment.

Answer (score 5):

The expression

```
x >= 3
```

is a pure comparison. It tests, whether the value of variable `x` is greater than, or equals 3. The result is `0` or `1` – for `x` equal `2` it is zero, false.

Terminating the expression with a semicolon creates a statement. That statement performs a comparison and ...nothing else. The result of comparison is discarded, and the variable `x` remains unchanged. Hence the observed resulting value `2`.

---

In `x = x > 3;` the subexpression `x > 3` is a comparison. Its result is `1` if the comparison succeedes, `0` otherwise.

Since you initialized `x` to `2`, the result of the comparison is false, i.e. zero.

As a result

```
x = x > 3;
```

equivalent to

```
x = (x > 3);
```

resolves to

```
x = 0;
```

hence the output you observed.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
int x = 2;
x >= 3;
cout << x;
```

the output is `2` because the result of the `x >= 3` operation is discarded (not used) and `x` remains by the same value as it were initialized. `x` was not assigned by any value after its initialization.

---

If you use

```
int x = 2;
x = x > 3;
cout << x;   `
```

`x` is checked whether it is greater than `3` or not with `x > 3`. If it is, the value of the expression `x > 3` turns `1`, if not it turns `0`. Comparison operations are [*boolean expressions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression).

This boolean value is assigned back to `x` after the evaluation of `x > 3`.

Since `x` is not greater than `3`, the expression `x > 3` gains the value `0` and this value is assigned back to `x` and finally what is printed.